# Tablepress customising table css - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have custom CSS for my tablepress tables, but for one particular table I would like to include cell borders.  When I try to add my custom CSS code to the extra CSS classes section for that table, it tells me it is invalid.  Can you help?

The extra css is:

```
.tablepress td {   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; }
```

My custom CSS for all tables is

```
.tablepress {   background-color: #CDCDCD;  margin: 10px 0 15px 0;  font-size: 11pt;    width: 98%;     text-align: left; }

.tablepress th {    background-color: #E6EEEE;  border: 1px solid
#FFFFFF;    padding: 4px; }

.tablepress td {    color: #3D3D3D;     padding: 4px;   background-color:
#FFFFFF;    vertical-align: top; }

.tablepress .even td {  background-color: #FFFFFF; }

.tablepress .odd td {   background-color: #F0F0F6; }

.tablepress .header {   background-image: url(http://lifeinthefastlane.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/img/bg.gif);    background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: center right;  cursor: pointer; }

.tablepress .headerSortUp {     background-color: #8DBDD8;  background-image: url(http://lifeinthefastlane.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/img/asc.gif); }

.tablepress .headerSortDown {   background-color: #8DBDD8;  background-image: url(http://lifeinthefastlane.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/img/desc.gif); }
```

Comment: corrected now, sorry.

Comment: I pasted this code in the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options) and no errors are found. Maybe you should pass your whole CSS through it. . . Hint: when posting code here, try to use line breaks and indentation, it's easier for the reader (and potential helper) to parse the content without the horizontal scrollbar. Anyway, [Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) is a nice read :)